# How to solve nonlinear equations in R with Controls

Tags: r, equation, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I try to solve nonlinear equations with controls.

Here is my code:

```
fun <- function(x) {

  b0 <- (0.64*1+(1-0.64)*x[1]*(x[2]*x[1]-1)+x[1]*1*(1-x[2])*x[3])/(x[1]-1) -1805*2.85*0.64
  b1plus <-  (0.64*1+(1-0.64)*x[1]*(x[2]*x[1]-1.01)+x[1]*1.01*(1-x[2])*x[3])/(1.01*(x[1]-1)) -1805*2.85*0.64*(1+0.00235)
  b1minus <-  (0.64*1+(1-0.64)*x[1]*(x[2]*x[1]-0.99)+x[1]*0.99*(1-x[2])*x[3])/(0.99*(x[1]-1)) -1805*2.85*0.64*(1-0.00235)

  return(c(b0,b1plus,b1minus))
} 


multiroot(fun,c(1.5, 0, 0))
```

However, the result I get is far beyond the actual results. I wish to control x1 to the range (1.5,4), x2(0,1), x3(0,10000). How can I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: There are several other nonlinear equation solving packages over at CRAN, such as  `nleqslv`, that you could look at.  But here: how do you know the solution is close to the initial guess set you provided? And since these are simple polynomials, you might want to look at standard matrix methods.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're telling `multiroot` to try to get  your `b0,b1plus,b1minus` to be near those starting values, **not** the values of `x` which converge.

Comment: Ahh. that's because this is a repetition of my work in excel. The true value falls into a specific range to have meaning in real questions, but I get super large number that cannot be the actual results:)

Comment: OK, thank you. I am still trying to figure out how to use the multiroot to the right answer carefully:) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Methods like 'Newton-Raphson' in `multiroot` or `nleqslv` do not work well together with bounds constraints. One possible approach is to square and sum the components of your function

```
fun1 <- function(x) sum(fun(x)^2)
```

and then treat this as a global optimization problem where you hope for a minimum value of `0.0`. For example, *GenSA* provides an implementation of "simulated annealing" that works reasonably well in low dimensions.

```
library(GenSA)
res <- GenSA(par=NULL, fn=fun1,
             lower=c(1.5,0,0), upper=c(4,1,10000),
             control=list(maxit=10e5))
res$value; res$par
## [1] 119.7869
## [1]    4.00    0.00 2469.44
```

Several tries did not find a lower function value than this one, which makes me think there is no common root in the constraint box you requested.